# TYPO3 8.7: Extend sys_category with a new field

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I'm just trying to extend the sys_category table with a new field "page" just the normal extbase way. Worked like a charm, field shows up and is saved in DB. But there is no field in my f:debug in Fluid. Anyone got an idea what is missing?

Thanks a lot for any help!

TCA Override:

```
$newColumns = [
  'page' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:project/Resources/Private/Language/Default/locallang_db.xlf:sys_category.page',
    'config' => [
      'type' => 'group',
      'internal_type' => 'db',
      'allowed' => 'pages',
      'size' => 1,
      'maxitems' => 1,
      'minitems' => 0
    ]
  ],
];


\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('sys_category', $newColumns);

// Make fields visible in the TCEforms:
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
  'sys_category', // Table name
  'page', // Field list to add
  '1', // List of specific types to add the field list to. (If empty, all type entries are affected)
  'after:title' // Insert fields before (default) or after one, or replace a field
);
```

SQL:

```
#
# Table structure for table 'sys_category'
#
CREATE TABLE sys_category (
  page int(11),
);
```

Model:

```
<?php
namespace <Vendorname>\Project\Domain\Model;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility;

/**
 * Class Category
 * @package <Vendorname>\Project
 */

class Category extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $page = null;


    /**
     * Gets the page.
     *
     * @return integer
     * @api
     */
    public function getPage()
    {
        return $this->page;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the page.
     *
     * @param integer $page
     * @api
     */
    public function setPage($page)
    {
        $this->page = $page;
    }

}
```

Typoscript Setup:

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence {
    storagePid = {$plugin.tx_project.persistence.storagePid}
    classes {
        TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Category {
            subclasses {
                <Vendorname>\Project\Domain\Model\Category = <Vendorname>\Project\Domain\Model\Category
            }
        }

        <Vendorname>\Project\Domain\Model\Category {
            mapping {
                tableName = sys_category
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? Currently I want to do the same thing...

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure if it is possible to subclass the `sys_category` table of TYPO3.

If you always want that **all queries** to `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\CategoryRepository` will return objects of your custom type, you can configure your `ext_typoscript_setup` like shown below

```
config.tx_extbase{
    objects {
        TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Category.className = <vendor>\Project\Domain\Model\Category
    }
    persistence.classes {
        <vendor>\Project\Domain\Model\Category {
            mapping {
                tableName = sys_category
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note, that this will not include any other extensions on the table `sys_category` made by other TYPO3 extensions.

However, if you just need the extended `Category` object within your extension and not globally in TYPO3, you could create an own CategoryRepository in your extension like in [ext:news](https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/master/Classes/Domain/Repository/CategoryRepository.php)